# Format the output of a public function

Tags: vba, excel

How can I get the output of `IsMonday()` in date format? The value from the function currently is either true or false. I am trying to pass the pubic variable `dt` as a parameter for two other sub procedures.

```
Option Explicit
Public dt As Date

Sub test2()
MsgBox Date

MsgBox dt

MsgBox IsMonday(dt)

End Sub

Public Function IsMonday(inputdate As Date) As Boolean

    Select Case Weekday(inputdate)
        Case vbMonday
            dt = Date - 3              
            'dt = Format(dt, "mmddyyyy")
        Case Else
            dt = Date - 1
            'dt = Format(Date - 1, "mmddyyyy")          
            'dt = Format(dt, "mmddyyyy")
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Typically, when you use isSomething() it's supposed to return a Boolean True/False.  I think you are trying to manipulate the date somehow.

Comment: The value of the function is true or false because you specifically said it is supposed to be by having it return `Boolean`. Why would you expect something different to be returned?

Comment: Can you give some examples of the input and associated output you expect?

Comment: I plan to pass `public dt` through procedure 1 which evaluates `dt` through `IsMonday()` and then procedure 2 takes the user's raw input as `dt` Thus `IsMonday()` is only utilized through one procedure (Procedure 1). The Main Sub procedure is called with `dt` as a parameter, where the Main Sub imports a dated file based off of the public `dt` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to pass a value as a date from your function, you have to declare the result as Date...

```
Public Function IsMonday(inputdate As Date) As Date

    Select Case Weekday(inputdate)
        Case vbMonday
            dt = Date - 3              
            'dt = Format(dt, "mmddyyyy")
        Case Else
            dt = Date - 1
            'dt = Format(Date - 1, "mmddyyyy")          
            'dt = Format(dt, "mmddyyyy")
    End Select
IsMonday = dt
End Function
```